# How can I get my javascript work in an asp.net cshtml file?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a html input for uploading a picture to my ftp, and I want my JS the detect changes on my button. 
My cshtml is:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFile", "Upload", FormMethod.Post, new { 
    enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {

    <input id="uploadFile" placeholder="No file..." disabled="disabled" />
    <div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
        <span>Browse</span>
        <input id="uploadBtn" type="file" class="upload" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" title="OK" />
}
```

and my script is

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        document.getElementById("uploadBtn").onchange = function ()
        {
            document.getElementById("uploadFile").value = this.value;
        };
    </script>
</head>
```

When I run my code I get the following message:

> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'onchange' of undefined or null reference

I checked my html and JS in fiddle, everything works great, so I guess that Razor and JS have some problems with each others. 
Any tips?

Comment: Move your script to immediately before the closing `</body>` tag, or wrap it in `$(document).ready()

Comment: Agree to @StephenMuecke. Your script is trying to access button before its loaded in DOM.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Though I agree, if you are wrapping code inside `document.ready`, loading area will not matter. Also as an extension to your comment, if you have a lot of code, move it to a JS file and load it, instead of inline script

Comment: Moving my code just before the closing body tag changed nothing, I got the very same error message.

Comment: Tried wrapping my script in $(document).ready(), the error message gone, but my script doesn't work.

`<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            document.getElementById("uploadBtn").onchange = function () {
                document.getElementById("uploadFile").value = this.value;
            };
        });
</script>`

I put the script between the <head> tags, then just before the closing body tag, and get the same message from the debugger:
_The breakpoint will not be hit. No executable code of the debugger's target code type is associated with this line..._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
        document.getElementById("uploadBtn").onchange = function ()
        {
            document.getElementById("uploadFile").value = this.value;
        };
});
    </script>
</head>
```

2. **As per @StephenMuecke** : Move your script to immediately before the closing `</body>` tag (as my view it's best way)

   `<body> .............. .............`

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#uploadBtn').on('change', function() {
      $("#uploadFile").val($(this).val());
    })
   });   </script>
   ```

   `</body>`

3.If you use separate script (`.js` file) then try

```
     $(document).on('change','#uploadBtn' ,function() {
         $("#uploadFile").val($(this).val());
      });
```

Comment: @StephenMuecke. 
I tried everything you suggested, the code above and moving the script just before the end body tag, between head tags, moving to a .js file, everything. 
No error message now, but I said that I have a warning message (`The breakpoint will not be hit. No executable code of the debugger's target code type is associated with this line...`), but I get the same warning with another working script, so, it can't be the problem. Any other tips?

Comment: @K.Gabor check no 3

Comment: No 3 works great, No 1 as well (there was a code duplication I didn't notice, two buttons with the same ID, that caused the problem). 
Thanks guys, saved my day!